# Pine backtesting, doesn't open a new trade if there is one already opened

Tags: pine-script

The titles says it all, here is my code.

```
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="InsBarSE")
        strategy.exit("Short", loss=200, profit=200, when=exit_long)

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="InsBarLE")
        strategy.exit("Long", loss=200, profit=200, when=exit_short)
```

a lot of times the short trade closes the long trade automatically, and I don't want that to happen, I want them to go until it hits profit or loss, help please.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the `from_entry=` parameter for your `strategy.exit()` calls, so they are exiting any open trade. See the [refman](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit) for details. Your code should look like:

```
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="InsBarSE")
        strategy.exit("Exit Short", "Short", loss=200, profit=200, when=exit_long)

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="InsBarLE")
        strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Long", loss=200, profit=200, when=exit_short)
```